# Hide ComboboxItem if contains some string

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

Is there a way to collapse or hide some ComboBoxItems if contain some specific string?

I was trying

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem b in cboServers.Items)
{
      if (b.Content.ToString().Contains("prod")) 
      { b.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; } 
      else 
      { b.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; }
}
```

but is not working because ComboBoxItem can't be converted to String

```
//Read file's content. 
foreach (IniSection ContainerForThisServer in iniFile.Sections) 
{ 
    cboServidores.Items.Add(ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper()); 
    FillTab(ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper(), ContainerForThisServer); 
}
```

Comment: Hm I'm not sure you can hide and show combobox items. I'd potentially go down the route of removing/adding items instead. so you could have a for loop instead and use cboServers.Items.Remove(cboServers.Items.ElementAt(i)) or something like that? I can write the code in an answer if that'd be more helpful.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I think .Remove could be usefull!

Comment: It's working fine for me... can you provide the code used to populate the combobox pls?

Comment: have you got a collection bound to combo box ?

Comment: Mmmm Sorry to be so stupid, i don’t know what is that. I populate the combobox with Combobox.Items.Add

Comment: show us the code where you add items

Comment: Rather than trying to hide or remove items in the combo box, the combobox should be bound to a list with the correct items. If you want to display a filtered list, bind to a second list that is filtered version of the first list.

Comment: Yes! this is my code //Read file's content.
            foreach (IniSection ContainerForThisServer in iniFile.Sections)
            {
                cboServers.Items.Add(ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper());
                FillTab(ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper(), ContainerForThisServer);
            }

Comment: Your code to collapse visibility based on a condition is correct and working fine. Also you can try removing your elements and store them somewhere if you want to repopulate those items in future during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesnt work because you are adding items in upper case and your if statement checks for lower case "prod" but instead why not stop items from going into combo box ?

```
foreach (IniSection ContainerForThisServer in iniFile.Sections) 
{ 
    if (b.Content.ToString().Contains("prod"))
    {
        cboServidores.Items.Add(ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper()); 
        FillTab(ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper(), ContainerForThisServer); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Also if you wanna work on WPF a lot, start reading about bindings and MVVM

Comment: Yes, thanks! But is there a way to Remove or hide items?

Comment: there are lots and lots of ways for doing it, did you change lowercase "prod" to "PROD"

Comment: @GermanMartin you can remove items by **cboServers.Items.Remove(index)**
pass index after finding that element.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<ComboBoxItem> hiddenItems = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
foreach (ComboBoxItem b in cboServers.Items)
{
    if (b.Text.Contains("PROD")) 
    { 
        hiddenItems.Add(b);
    }
}

foreach (ComboBoxItem hiddenItem in hiddenItems) 
{
    cboServers.Items.Remove(hiddenItem);
}
//hiddenItems now contains everything that was hidden if you want to use it at a later date
```

hopefully that helps?

Comment: Hi Dan, With your code I have the same problem:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem' to type 'System.String'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I must use:

```
foreach (IniSection ContainerForThisServer in iniFile.Sections) { 
ComboBoxItem i = new ComboBoxItem();
                i.Content = ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper();
                cboServers.Items.Add(i);
 }
```

instead of:

```
foreach (IniSection ContainerForThisServer in iniFile.Sections) { cboServers.Items.Add(ContainerForThisServer.Name.ToUpper()); 
 }
```

and now Visibility and Collapsed works perfect without using .Remove()

```
foreach (ComboBoxItem b in cboServers.Items)
{
      if (b.Content.ToString().ToLower().Contains("prod")) 
      { b.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; } 
      else 
      { b.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; }
}
```